# Lorentz Transformation of Wave Equation

Tags: special-relativity, waves, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, velocity

Consider a 1D Wave equation: $$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=v_1^2\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}$$ So, we are given two frames, S and S' (moving along $x$-axis) with velocity $V$ relative to S. I want to check whether the equation is Lorentz invariant or not. So, during the transformation, in the equations:
$$x'= \gamma (x-v t)$$
$$t'= \gamma (t-\frac{v x}{c^2})$$
What should I put in place of $v$? Should it be the frame velocity $V$ or the velocity of the wave in frame S' (obtained using velocity-addition formula)?

Answer (score 1):

$v$ in the transformation equations is the relative velocity between the frames of reference.